# SOQL to get Accounts with more than 3 contacts

Tags: apex, soql

I want to query and get Accounts which are having more than 3 contacts. Please let me know how to achieve this.

started with this SOQL:

```sql
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Name FROM Contacts) FROM Account
```

and tried to give aggregate function in contact query using group by but its not supported in inner query.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You should [edit] your question to include those details

Comment: @DerekF added the query where i started and any modifications on that is failing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an Aggregate Result query, such as:

```
select accountid from contact group by accountid having count(id) > 3
```

Note that you'll be limited to 2000 results if you use this method. Otherwise, you'd need some sort of Rollup Summary field in order to use this sort of query.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox , it helps